# How to use command line to Reserve ParaID locally

Tags: polkadot, validator, relay-chain

Regarding this tutorial "Connect a local parachain": https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-other-chains/local-parachain/, it requires

- using GUI in a browser to Reserve a ParaID on the relay chain (that is to use Polkadot-JS Apps connecting to your local relay chain)

I have searched on that Polkadot-launch repo https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch/ and found nothing about that.

How can I use a command line(e.g. NodeJs) to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code on how would you do it:

```js
@import polkadot_api;

let reserver = 0xa_address_is_here;
let registrar.reserve(reserver, 2000);
```

Here is what [`registrar.reserve`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/9804117d3e676aace31ed39569a4e6aec75956de/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L344) do.

Also refer to polkadot guide on [how to call transaction](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.tx) and [how to call rpc](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/rpc.custom).

At this point, you sucessfully reserved a paraId. Now you can proceed to [register parachain](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3848/2384)